# Smart GWT: ListGrid.createRecordComponent () is not called for all rows

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I am using Smart GWT 2.5. I am using a List Grid in my project.

The List Grid has 20 rows, but `ListGrid.createRecordComponent()` is called for only first 16 rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incremental rendering, which is on by default.

You could force all records to be rendered via ListGrid.setShowAllRecords(true), but you probably don't want to do this unless you are sure the total number of records will remain small (less than around 100 if you need to support IE).